# php processing / variable in php file that generates xml file of markers

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

Ive been trying to solve some issues for implementing google maps with the api using this guidehttp://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html.

Im stuck at this part: modifying the query with a variable set in another document or in the same document with processing of server basename like this:

*(this is the php file that generates the xml file:http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_genxml3.php)*

```
$mapid = str_replace(".php","",basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE type='".$mapid."'";
```

This doesnt work...

Also it doesn't work if i set the variable in the main webpage.php file that displays the map eighter... it works if i set the variable in the same file (xmlgenerate.php) like this:

```
$mapid = "mymap";
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE type='".$mapid."'";
```

Hope someone can tell me what im doing wrong here.

edit: Heres a link to the live files btw. xmlgenerate=> http://www.pinnedmap.com/mapdata.php and mappage=> http://www.pinnedmap.com/test.php NB. a valid query example is: wondersoftheworld

to pass the variable from test.php would be ideal.

Comment: You have an SQL Injection venerability here..

Comment: Could you also please explain in more detail what is going wrong.

Comment: Edited the question a little. Hope it is clearer now..? Thx for notifying abt the vulnerability btw!

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  What errors do you get?  Can you post the client side code, can you post a link to it live?

Comment: What's the `request_uri`, i.e. what you expect it to be? We still don't have enough information to help you

Comment: I basically need a unique identifier for each map (wepage1.php, webpage2.php etc) that the sql query can read based on what file the visitor is viewing. (request_uri should be the file that the browser is displaying ie. webpage1.php -> the xmlgenerate.php should be the same file all the tim except variables for the query should change on what file is displayed in the browser)

Comment: Can't you just use `$_GET`? If your user calls `something.php?hello=test` then `$_GET['hello'] == 'test'`

Comment: btw i have a feeling it has to do with that the xmlgenerate is just being included with simplexml_load_file. ive also tried requireing it tho inside the document but it doesnt work and idk if it makes sense even.

Comment: Not trying to be rude here but you probably need to learn a bit more of PHP if you've never heard of `$_GET` before you attempt at something like this

Comment: its alright. well i dont have variables in the url.. just www.site.com/webpage.php. i guess i can modify it to use variables  in there if it works. ill post back :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do here:

```
$mapid = str_replace(".php","",basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Instead try this:

```
$mapid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['mapid']);
```

(The `mysql_real_escape_string` part prevents a SQL injection)

Now just request your file like `file.php?mapid=something` and everything should work...

Comment: when i change that code and enter file.php?mapid=mymapid in the address field it doesnt change anything it seems.